# Failed to create migration. EF Core tools is older than some version

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create an Init migration for my simple project.
But I am getting next error:

```
C:\RiderProjects\Architecture\Architecture>dotnet ef migrations add init
The EF Core tools version '2.1.8-servicing-32085' is older than that of the runtime '2.2.2-servicing-10034'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
Unable to create an object of type 'DomainContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Which doesn't make any sence, because if we take alook at my NuGet dependencies:

[image]

there is no older Core.Tools version - it is 2.2.2.

Here is my Context class (maybe the problem is hidden inside this class):

```
public class DomainContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DomainContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public DbSet<Car> Car { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Location { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(CompanyMapping.Config);
    }
}
```

Could anybody please suggest the solution ?
**EDIT**
Here is `.csproj` file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="SimpleInjector" Version="4.4.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

**BIG UPDATE**

Make sure you have default constructor for Context Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your .csproj file. Maybe there is an older version targeted in a PackageReference node.

Comment: Sir, I have attached the file. Seems there is no older version. Unfortunately.

Comment: Hm, ok. Can you try to reinstall core tools to the latest/desired version (i.e. Package Manager console: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.2.2)? Maybe there is a mismatch under the hood that gets fixed by that.

Comment: Or "dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 2.2.2" if you're working with .NET CLI.

Comment: still no luck. I have a sense that maybe somewhere the versions are cached ? Or it is not the case ?

Comment: Sorry to hear that - at the moment I don't have any other suggestions but would come back to this if I get to know something that may help you. I'm not aware of any caching concerning this issue.

Comment: Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Maybe another idea: What version of the .Net Core SDK have you installed (dotnet --version)? Can you install the latest version and check again (not the preview, so 2.2.2 should be the latest stable version).

Comment: Hmm, since I've updated sdk now I am only getting 'Unable to create an object of type 'DomainContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time' error.